# How can I execute javascript from the server when using asp:UpdatePanels?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I used to do the following to execute javascript from the server:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( ... );
```

And it would execute when the page loads back at the client. I am now modifing existing pages to use `UpdatePanels` and my javascript is no longer being fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIR, you should use `ScriptManager`'s `RegisterStartupScript` method. For details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)